# RKObjectMapping mapping issue in restkit 10.0

Tags: ios, json, web-services, restkit

I am confused with RKObjectMapping in new restkit 10.0.
I have invoked my webservice with RKClient and got response in the form of JSON.
Now I want to map the JSON string with my User class .
How to do it ?

```
{"id":2,"displayName":"Giri Bhushan","roles":null,"username":"FBUser-123456","password":"dddddddddddddddd=\r\n","email":"test@gmail.com","gender":"M","birthDate":null,"friends":null,"bloodGroup":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"phoneNumber":null}
```

I have tried with below code :

```
RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"userId"];

[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"displayName" toAttribute:@"displayName"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"userName" toAttribute:@"userName"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"password" toAttribute:@"password"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"email" toAttribute:@"email"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"gender" toAttribute:@"gender"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"birthDate" toAttribute:@"birthDate"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"bloodGroup" toAttribute:@"bloodGroup"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstName" toAttribute:@"firstName"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastName" toAttribute:@"lastName"];

[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"phoneNumber" toAttribute:@"phoneNumber"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:userMapping forKeyPath:@"user"];
```

But, how do I map the JSON string with RKObjectMapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you have *users* at the root level of your JSON, the following should work:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKManagedObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class] inManagedObjectStore:manager.objectStore];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"userId"];
[userMapping mapAttributes:@"displayName",@"userName",@"password", nil]; // Add other attributes
[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:userMapping forKeyPath:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this line:
`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"" delegate:self];`

then implement its delegate method like:
`(void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects{
    NSLog(@"Objects Retrieved: %d\n%@", objects.count, objects);

    YourObject* obj = [objects objectAtIndex:0];`

```
NSString* info = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                  @"Value 1 is %@\n"
                  @"Value 2 is %@\n"
                  @"Value 3 is: %@",
                  [obj value1],
                  [obj value2],
                  [obj value3];
```

}`

Hope this works for you. XD